# Stationary Distribution for Markov-like system?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, matrices, na.numerical-analysis, stochastic-processes

Let 
\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} \\
a_{2,1} & 0 & a_{2,3} \\
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
with $a_{i,j}>=0$ (no stochastic matrix) and $\pi\in\mathbb{R_{}}_{+}^3$.
The system I want to solve is
\begin{equation}
\langle\pi,\pi B\rangle=\pi A
\end{equation},
where $\langle.,.\rangle: \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is the elementwise multiplication of two vectors. Via programming, I found that with an arbitrary starting vector $\pi_0\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^3$, the following sequence converges to the desired solution $\pi$:
\begin{equation}
\pi_{i+1}:=\frac{\pi_{i}A}{\pi_{i}B},
\end{equation}
where the fraction is again elementwise.

Can anyone help me prove existence and uniqueness of a solution (except the trivial one) to the system via this convergence? It looks a bit like the stationary distribution of irreducible Markov Chains, but it is different.

Also thankful for references to literature or other posts here. Thanks!

Remark: I already asked a quite similar question on Stackexchange Mathematics (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709568/how-to-solve-this-system-of-3-equations-with-3-variables) but did not get an answer. I thought MathOverflow would be more suited for the question. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: Are you interested in nonnegative solutions only? Otherwise, my guess is that the solution is not unique in general.

Comment: there's a syntax error: $\langle \pi, \pi B\rangle$ is a scalar, whereas $\pi A$ is not...

Comment: @Federico: Thx, only nonnegative solutions.

Comment: @Suvrit: No, both are vectors.

Comment: @Suvrit $\langle \pi, \pi B\rangle$ is not what you think, from the description it should be the Hadamard product.

Comment: that's terrible notation then I'd say!

Comment: I don't want to oversell this, but your proposed solution looks like a matrix version of something I saw in a book by Neil Madras.  While reviewing Markov chains, he gives such a criteria for a solution.

Comment: Shameless self-advertising: I have studied a similar problem in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379511004484 and http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/100796765.

Our problem comes from modelling Markovian binary trees with multiple states; I wouldn't be surprised if yours has the same origin.

Maybe we can reduce one setting to the other with a change of variable of the form $x=\begin{bmatrix}C\\C\\C\end{bmatrix}-\pi$ for some $C>0$ (a change of variable that we use in the second paper that I have linked).

Comment: @MartinBuber How do you divide vectors? Elementwise?

Comment: @Piotr: Yes, that's what I meant by "where the fraction is again elementwise" :)